# Difference in Get Variable Location

Tags: php, url-rewriting, variables

I have noticed that in some instances in WordPress (such as in my custom post types), GET variables appear as following in the URL:

www.url.com/events/cool-event?action=edit&message=1

However, in other instances (such as when I am pointing to my login 'virtual' page which I created using the rewrite API), the urls look like this:

www.url.com/login/?action=login

As you can see, there is a forward slash before the first variable.  What is causing this?  Which one is the normal way for them to appear?  Is there any functional difference?  And finally, assuming that it makes sense, how can I make them both behave in a similar manner?

- William

### Update

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_virtual_page_template' );
function add_virtual_page_template()
{
    global $wp, $wp_rewrite;

    $wp->add_query_var( 'template' );

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'login', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'login/?', 'index.php?template=login', 'top' );

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_virtual_page_redirect' );

function add_virtual_page_redirect()
{
    global $wp;

    $queryvar = get_query_var('template');

    if ($queryvar && $queryvar == 'login')
    {
        include(site_url('wp-login.php'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "normal" way (either is commonplace), but it all comes down to your permalink structure, and whether *that* has a trailing slash or not.

As for your login page, it all depends on how you're generating the URLs, but I would suggest using `user_trailingslashit( $basepath_without_query )`.

As the name suggests, it will apply (or remove) trailing slashes to match the configured permalink structure.

Comment: Hey - I have included that snippet that I use to generate the URL - how would I implement your solution?